# LED PSU for pulsed load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I've bought a cheap LED strip SMPS - 120 W / 24 V - with the intention to supply a couple of solenoids (15 W each) and an electronic device (around 4 W) with it. I'll never draw more than 80 W from it.

The problem with it is that there's some "intelligent" Green-Power function in the controller. Firstly, there was that burst-mode thing that wouldn't produce a stable voltage when there's no load, but I've come around it with a 1k / 1 W resistor. I thought this will be enough for my purposes, but when I apply a load instantaneously (70 W for example), the output voltage starts dropping like a stone, then the controller starts increasing the output power but way too late, some short-circuit condition gets triggered, the SMPS goes through a reset and only after that (1-2 seconds later) it restarts, producing a stable voltage/power.

Note that, however, this only happens when there's been a long steady state between the load step. Around 3-5 seconds. If I start switching the load at a faster rate - 1W - 70W - 1W - 70W and so on, every second for example - the output voltage stays to spec - constant 24 V with no more than 0.2 V of ripple.

There's some internal power/frequency scaling that i'm guessing is part of the Green-Power control. For example, if I increase the power step interval to 2-3 seconds, the output voltage drops by a couple of volts in the beginning, but does not invoke a reset cycle.

I found out (upon disassembly) that the SMPS is based on a CR6842 On-line PWM controller.

AC coupled DC output ripple, fast switching load 1 W / 70 W:
[image: AC coupled DC output ripple, fast switching load 1 W / 70 W]

Reset condition after a steady load:
[image: Reset condition after a steady load]

DC coupled output at different switching speeds - no drop, drop, and a drop followed by a reset:
[image: DC coupled output at different switching speeds - no drop, drop, and a drop followed by a reset]

So... Is there some way to trick the chip into constant power mode? Is this the expected behaviour? Or should I not bother at all and buy another PSU that suits my purpose better? Will a DIN-rail SMPS be any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a trivial problem!

PSU is working according to spec - It's designed to turn off immediately when overloaded.

My mistake was that I was considering that a halogen test bulb (70W) is a suitable substitute for the solenoid load.
In fact, when the filament is cold, its inrush current is so high that it triggers the short-circuit protection.
Again, according to the observation, if the bulb has been operating less than ~5 s before, the filament is hot enough to cause only a voltage drop, and if operation is frequent enough (< 3s), inrush current is low enough for the PSU to regulate.

Answer (score 0):

Scope pin 7 (Vdd) of the [CR6842](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/631854/ChipRail/CR6842/1) to see what it is doing during "reset".  Perhaps the Vdd just drops out due to its bypass cap being too small of a value.

Minimalist design; I'm assuming they skimped here and used a small-value cap.

Comment: So I managed to scope it but it behaves exactly like the output. The only difference is that unloaded VDD is at 13 V and with a 70 W load it goes to 14.6 V. There's also a zener diode accross VDD. Apart from that - when I load it after more than 5 seconds of low load, power increases (VDD goes 14.6 and more) and then the PWM stops/resets. If I load it at shorter intervals, PSU regulates normally. I can attach oscillograms if needed.

Comment: Load is mostly resistive - a halogen lamp. VDD cap is 47 uF.